# Apparently erroneous initialization of class template member compiles just fine

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang, language-lawyer

Consider the following MCVE code:

```cpp
struct Id { static inline int id(int c) {return c;} };

template <class C>
class Foo {
    C m_bar;
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int) : m_bar{bar} {} // Fails in clang, compiles in gcc/msvc
    Foo(int, int) : m_bar(bar) {} // Compiles with all gcc/clang/msvc
    Foo(int, int, int) : m_bar(Id::id(bar)) {} // Compiles in gcc/msvc with both () and {} syntax, fails for both in clang

    C bar() const { return m_bar; }
};
```

For simplicity, let's assume I instantiate `Foo<int> x;`. I would expect all of the constructors to produce a compile error, because I am trying to initialize `m_bar` with `bar`, which is a *method* (not that I am not calling `bar` here).

But all variants compile on all major compilers, with the only exception of clang in `Foo(int)`.

Note that all compilers fail as expected when I call the corresponding constructor overload, e.g. `Foo<int> f{1};`. But from my understanding it is the *class* which is a template, not the *constructor*, so I would expect all constructors to fail when instantiating the class template, even the the unused ones.

Interestingly, when using a non-template class like below, all three constructors fail as expected:

```cpp
class Foo {
    int m_bar;
public:
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(int) : m_bar{bar} {} // fails in all gcc/clang/msvc
    Foo(int, int) : m_bar(bar) {} // fails in all gcc/clang/msvc
    Foo(int, int, int) : m_bar{Id::id(bar)} {} // fails in all gcc/clang/msvc

    int bar() const { return m_bar; }
};
```

For convenience, here is the [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8daYqqhjM) link with the compiler outputs.

My question is: Is this a bug in all three compilers or is there some misconception from my side, maybe some obscure section in the standard that explains this behavior?

Comment: Can you add to this post a [mre] of the code and the errors it gives you?  Not a lot of people like to click in links and have to edit code to try and preproduce the issue.

Comment: Is the `#if 1` meant to toggle the error? I tried with both `#if 0` and `#if 1` and all compilers compiled fine.

Comment: In addition, that godbolt link won't last forever, and if the information at the link is necessary to understand the question, the question will be "Not useful" in the near future.

Comment: @NathanOliver: This actually _is_ the reproducible example. It should suffice to compile the snippet with a quick command. The instantiation of `Foo` is optional. And it's the error messages that I'm missing, so there's not much to show either. I can mark it with a language-lawyer tag if that helps.

Comment: I am not sure why only clang catches it, but try using one of the other constructors (like `Foo(5)` here https://godbolt.org/z/c6codf1x5). All fail

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux no I commented out some ctors. But I was hoping the question would be clear from my explanation :-/ maybe I just remove the godbolt link altogether, I added it for convenience...

Comment: @user4581301 I don't think the link is necessary to understand the question. As mentioned before, I just added the link for convenience so one can see the compiler outputs. This is a quite common thing at StackOverflow. I dont think this makes my question "not useful".

Comment: It isn't clear why clang thinks `{bar}` is bad and `(bar)` is ok in an uninstantiated member function. However the standard says "The validity of a template *may* (emphasis mine) be checked prior to any instantiation", which probably means that there is no obligation to do such checks. The standard also says "The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:...no valid specialization can be generated for a template ... and the template is not instantiated". It isn't clear whether this applies to instantiation of member functions of class templates.

Comment: If you don't use a method on a templated class (a constructor), the compiler is allowed to not even bother with creating those methods. When you say `Foo<int> x`, you're calling the defaulted constructor, which does not perform any erroneous initialization. So long as the code is syntactically correct, it can (and does) work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class template members are instantiated on-demand. See [[temp.inst]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#9):

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a variable template, a member template, **a non-virtual member function**, a member class, a static data member of a class template, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement, unless such instantiation is required.

Also, since `m_bar` depends on the template parameter, the expression `m_bar{bar}` can't be syntax-checked during template parsing.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for pointing to that paragraph. So it appears to me that this is a bug in clang? The standard explicitly states "shall not", and clang fails even when there's no instantiation at all. Moreover it's failing only when using uniform initialization syntax (`m_bar(bar)` compiles just fine), which is at least inconsistent (obviously narrowing doesn't play any role here).

Comment: Well, clang says `error: reference to non-static member function must be called`, which is kind of true, `bar` is a non-static member, so it can appear unqualified only in a call. Clang is just being helpful here, after all the code has no chance of ever working.

Comment: That was my thought and in fact it was because of clang that I discovered such a mistake in some piece of code that had been untouched for years. And to be honest I like this diagnostics better, because it reveals a true issue. But in the strict sense, could one call it a bug because it does not conform to the standard?

Comment: "The validity of a template may be checked prior to any instantiation".

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. you had mentioned it before but I cannot find that statement in [\[temp\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp). Can you provide a resource? I think that would be the missing piece to the puzzle, although the "may" leads to some inconsistency in this case (`()` vs `{}`).

Comment: @andreee https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp#res.general-6

Comment: Ah, this is >=C++20... my question was targeted at C++17. Unfortunately I had removed the c++17 tag because to replace it with language-lawyer... anyway, looks like in C++17, this statement does not apply.

Comment: It's [\[temp.res\]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#8) in C++17, which says simply "Knowing which names are type names allows the syntax of every template to be checked.", for the rest it's pretty much the same.